# G-suite license management via Enterprise License Manager v1 API in Python

Tags: python, google-api

I managed to authenticate to the licensing API using googleapiclient.discovery

But I can't seem to be able to navigate it:

```
creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('licensing', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    service.LicenseAssignment().list(productId='Google-Apps', customerId='someCustomerID').execute()
```

How can I use ther service similar to the user management one:

```
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10, orderBy='email').execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had a typo:

```
service.licenseAssignments().listForProduct(productId='Google-Apps', customerId='someCustomerID').execute
```

and everything is working as expected